# Ant, JUnit, and a TestSuite

Tags: java, ant, junit

So I'm setting up automatic regression testing with JUnit, and right now the build script is set up to call a TestSuite, which packs a bunch of different tests into a TestSuite and returns it.

buildfile:

```
<target name="test-perform-check" depends="test-compile">
        <junit printsummary="yes" fork="yes" haltonfailure="no">
            <classpath path ="${mypath}"  />
            <jvmarg value="-Djava.ext.dirs=${extstar};${extpathextended};" />
                    <jvmarg value="-Dmipav=${mipav};" />
            <sysproperty key="mipav" value="${mipav}"/>
           <formatter type="xml"/>
           <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
           <test name="test.JTest"/>
        </junit>
    </target>
```

JTest.java:

```
 class JTest extends TestSuite {

    public static Test suite () {
        // set up a bunch of stuff
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTest(new VolumeCompare());
        suite.addTest(new VolumeCompare());
        suite.addTest(new VolumeCompare());
        suite.addTest(new FileExistence());
        // do some other stuff
        return suite;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[junit] Testcase: null took 0.002 sec
[junit]     FAILED
[junit] null
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
[junit] 
[junit] Testcase: null took 0 sec
[junit]     FAILED
[junit] null
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
[junit] 
[junit] Testcase: null took 0.002 sec
[junit]     FAILED
[junit] null
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
[junit] 
[junit] Testcase: null took 0 sec
[junit]     FAILED
[junit] null
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
[junit] 
[junit] Test test.JTest FAILED
```

My question is - what do I need to change in the buildscript to make ant run the tests properly?

Edit:

VolumeCompare.java:

```
public class VolumeCompare extends TestCase {
    public VolumeCompare (...) {
        // ctor
    }
    @Test
    public void testVolume () {
        // this print statement is never reached
        System.out.println("testing volume");
        // compare volumes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `VolumeCompare.java` file?

Comment: Posted.  Still poking around with it, if I manage to fix it I'll throw it up there.

Answer (score 0):

From the [junit task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html), I think the test attribute has to be used with a class that contains a single Test (rather than a Suite). Maybe you can use a pattern to ask ant to run every test in a given package, like this :

```
  <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.tests}">
   <fileset dir="${src.tests}">
     <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
     <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
   </fileset>
  </batchtest>
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't *want* ant to run all of the tests right away.  I have a bunch of stuff to do before I run the tests (crunch a lot of numbers) and I don't want to return the TestSuite until that is done.

Comment: Oh right, that's what you meant by 'setup a bunch of stuff', sorry. You always have the option to set up an ant task to do this number chunching, and then make your test task depend on this number crunching task - of course it will depend on how the Test classes use this number crunching ... do you pass data to your Test class ctor ? or is it stored in db / file ?

Comment: Okay, so I found other articles doing pretty much the same as you  (http://opensource-soa.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-run-junit-test-suite-from-ant.html). So maybe the issue is actually in your test themselves - but it's hard to tell with what you have posted ...

Answer (score 0):

When using a TestSuite you add test cases to your suite one testcase at a time, your syntax should look more like this:

```
suite.addTest(new VolumeCompare("testCase1"));
suite.addTest(new VolumeCompare("testCase2"));
suite.addTest(new VolumeCompare("testCase3"));
```

Basically you aren't passing the name of a test to run and so it tries to run "null" and fails.